# data cannot save into MySQL using flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, database, flask

this is my HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action ="/">
   <td >student 1<input type="text" name="name"></td>
   <td>        
      <label for="mark"></label>
      <input type="number"  name="mark" min="1" max="10"  name="question1" id="question1">&nbsp /10
</form>
</td>
<td>
   <label for="mark"></label>
   <input type="number"  name="mark" min="1" max="10"  name="question2" id="question2">&nbsp /10</form>
</td>
<td>
   <label for="mark"></label>
   <input type="number"  name="mark" min="1" max="10"  name="question3" id="question3">&nbsp /10</form>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="submit" id="submit-button1">
   </form>
```

this is my FLASK APP code and the database connect function

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import processor

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'dbnlp'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def storename():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name'] 
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (%s)",(name))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the database name is dbnlp as created in my Mysql and the table name is user, the user attribute only two that is ID (auto increment) and name (the attribute that use to store the name)
i just want to store name only into database

hi, after i run the app.py, the name i submit in the html form cannot store into database and there is no error for me. i cannot detect what error..
anyone can help me on this trouble, thank a lot for the explanation.

Comment: try to run your app in development environment to see what errors out

Comment: @etch_45 It's already in development enviroment , they printing test statements in after if statement , see if it prints. I will suggest you to use flask-sqlalchemy as it support many databases.https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: The server logs (in the terminal where you are running flask) should contain the error traceback.  Please [edit] the question to include the traceback.

Comment: this show up only after i run, when press the submit button, it nothing happen @snakecharmerb
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2021 16:16:44] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 305-171-729
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: The values argument to `cursor.execute` must be a tuple - it should be `cur.execute("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (%s)", (name,))` - note the comma `,` after `name`.